# How can I trim a WAV file?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, wav

I need to trim a .wav file in wp7. I have some some code but it's not working. Does anyone know how to trim a wav file in windows phone 7?

Below is the code that I have that doesn't work.

```
    public IsolatedStorageFileStream TrimWavFile(string FileName, TimeSpan cutFromStart, TimeSpan cutFromEnd)
    {
        long start = Convert.ToInt64((16 / 8) * 16000 * cutFromStart.TotalSeconds);
        long end = Convert.ToInt64((16 / 8) * 16000 * cutFromEnd.TotalSeconds);

        IsolatedStorageFile storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = storage.OpenFile(FileName as string, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[stream.Length];
        stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);


        return TrimWavFile(stream, start, end);
    }

    private IsolatedStorageFileStream TrimWavFile(IsolatedStorageFileStream reader, long startPos, long endPos)
    {   
        IsolatedStorageFile storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        IsolatedStorageFileStream writer = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("t",  FileMode.OpenOrCreate,storage);

        reader.Position = startPos;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        while (reader.Position < endPos)
        {
            int bytesRequired = (int)(endPos - reader.Position);
            if (bytesRequired > 0)
            {
                int bytesToRead = Math.Min(bytesRequired, buffer.Length);
                int bytesRead = reader.Read(buffer, 0, bytesToRead);
                if (bytesRead > 0)
                {
                    writer.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
            }
            Makewav.WriteHeader(writer, (int)writer.Length - 44, 1, 16000);
        }
        return writer;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the wave header in the loop, I moved it out of the loop, removed the -44 in the `writer.length`.

I just had to seek the stream back to the beginning and it worked.

Comment: Congrats on the fix.  When you are able, make sure to accept your answer so others can learn from your solution.  Cheers~

Answer (score 1):

First, it doesn't look like you are accounting for the wav header when you are skipping to your startPos, so your placement will be off.

Secondly I'm guessing there may be a block alignment issue. Does it come out as static when you try to play it? Some sample code from NAudio showing how to trim a wav file ( http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.com/2009/09/trimming-wav-file-using-naudio.html ) shows this:

```
startPos = startPos - startPos % reader.WaveFormat.BlockAlign;
```

So you just need to figure out your block align size and calculate it like that, most likely. Same with your end position.

Comment: I had to move  Makewav.WriteHeader(writer, (int)writer.Length, 1, 16000); 
outside the while loop and seek back to the start of the stream. that was the fix

Answer (score 0):

In order to find the header information such as sample rate, num samples... etc, you may need to read the WAV File Specification https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/

This open source project http://code.google.com/p/musicg/ may give a reference for you. It's written in Java but the trimming logic is the same.